Can the AutoSuggestBox's suggestion area be forced to only expand downwards?
With an AutoSuggestBox, its suggestion area seems to vary between expanding upwards or downwards from the control. Presumably this is a best estimate based on the space available to the control.
Is it possible to ensure that the AutoSuggestBox's suggestion list will only ever expand downwards?

The following works with one caveat: the list will be reversed when the Popup was supposed to open upwards.
private void AutoSuggestBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs _)
{
    if (sender is not AutoSuggestBox autoSuggestBox ||
        VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(autoSuggestBox, 0) is not Grid grid ||
        grid.Children.FirstOrDefault(gridChild => gridChild is Popup) is not Popup popup ||
        (popup.Child as Border)?.Child is not ListView popupListView)
    {
        return;
    }

    popup.Opened += (sender, _) =>
    {
        popupListView.ScrollIntoView(popupListView.Items.FirstOrDefault());
        popup.VerticalOffset = autoSuggestBox.ActualHeight;
    };
}

